# CakePhp Model structuring

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1, cakephp-2.3

I am trying to create a relationship between three models.  My models are Roles, Responsibilities, and Employees.  Conceptually, I believe i would set the relationships up like this:

> ### Employee table:
>
> id:int Pk
>
> fName: varChar
>
> lName: varChar
>
> ### Role Table:
>
> roldId: int pk
>
> roleName: varChar
>
> ### Responsibility Table:
>
> reponsibilityId: PK int
>
> responsibilityName: varChar
>
> ### role_responsbility table:
>
> role_responsibility_id: PK int
>
> roleId: int FK
>
> responsibilityId int FK
>
> ### employee_role_responsibility Table:
>
> id: int PK
>
> role_responsibility_id int FK
>
> employee_id:  int FK

So, my question is, how do I model these relationships in my CakePHP model?  This is what i have so far:

```
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
class Employee extends AppModel {
    public  $name = "Employee";
}

App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
class Role extends AppModel {
    public  $name = "Role";

    public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
        'MemberOf' => array(
            'className' => 'Responsibility',
        )
    );
}

App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
class Responsibility extends  AppModel {
    public  $name = "Responsibility";

    public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
        'MemberOf' => array(
            'className' => 'Role',
        )
    );
}
```

How do I join the roles_responsbility table with the employee table?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're looking for [HasMany Through [see it in the CakePHP book]](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#hasmany-through-the-join-model), which basically explains that you can add additional fields to your join table, create model for that join table, and associate it however you want.

So, in your `responsibilities_roles` table, you'd add an `employee_id` field.

Then, you make a model called `RepsponsibilitiesRole` and set it to `belongsTo` `Employee`.

You can literally think of it as model of it's own, because that's what it is - so you can make methods in it, or run finds through it...etc etc etc.

Comment: Great, that seems to make sense.  So, what about views and controllers?  do the intermediary models need them?

Comment: They're not necessary unless you wanted to be able to access them via URL - in most cases, I don't create views or controllers for the go-between-model.